# pandas group by column, then summarise rows into list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform the dataframe called `annotations`

```
                 line_id  start  end  label
annotation_id                              
27229_36603_2_3        6    321  340    LOC
4                      8    200  203    PER
6                      8    262  268    PER
7                      8    262  281    ORG
10                    10     35   38    PER
12                    11    146  155    ORG
13                    11    156  164    ORG
```

such that for each `line_id`, there is exactly one row with a new column `annotation_list` that is to be generated from `start`, `end`, and `label` as a list.

The desired output is:

```
line_id   annotation_list

      6   [[321, 340, 'LOC']]
      8   [[200, 203, 'PER'], [262, 268, 'PER'], [262, 281, 'ORG']]
     10   [[35, 38, 'PER']]
     11   [[146, 155, 'ORG'], [156, 164, 'ORG']]
```

I have tried `groupby`, `aggregate`, and `apply` but could not reach the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html), aggregating as list of lists:

For all columns but `line_id`:

```
out = (df
   .set_index('line_id')                   # set aside
   .groupby('line_id')                     # for each group
   .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist()) # convert to list
   .reset_index(name='annotation_list')    # as dataframe
)
```

From a specific list of columns:

```
cols = ['start', 'end', 'label']
out = (df
   .groupby('line_id')[cols]               # for each group
   .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist()) # convert to list
   .reset_index(name='annotation_list')    # back to dataframe
)
```

Output:

```
   line_id                                      annotation_list
0        6                                    [[321, 340, LOC]]
1        8  [[200, 203, PER], [262, 268, PER], [262, 281, ORG]]
2       10                                      [[35, 38, PER]]
3       11                   [[146, 155, ORG], [156, 164, ORG]]
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's it! Seems like I was not too far off, the `.to_numpy().tolist()` did the trick.

Comment: @Daniel yes, unfortunately there is no direct way to convert from pandas

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function and columns names in list:

```
cols = ['start','end','label']

f = lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist()
df = df.groupby('line_id')[cols].apply(f).reset_index(name='annotation_list')
print (df)
   line_id                                    annotation_list
0        6                                  [[321, 340, LOC]]
1        8  [[200, 203, PER], [262, 268, PER], [262, 281, ...
2       10                                    [[35, 38, PER]]
3       11                 [[146, 155, ORG], [156, 164, ORG]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

at first use `apply` func, groupby + agg

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(list, axis=1).groupby(df['line_id']).agg(list)
```

output:

```
line_id
6                                     [[321, 340, LOC]]
8     [[200, 203, PER], [262, 268, PER], [262, 281, ...
10                                      [[35, 38, PER]]
11                   [[146, 155, ORG], [156, 164, ORG]]
dtype: object
```